# How to access single json file in html angular?

Tags: json, express, scope, ngroute

**This is boardview.html**

```
<div ng-controller="BoardController">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">
           {{board.title}}
       </div>
   <div class="panel-heading">
        {{board.writer}}
   </div>
</div>
```

**this is my partial appRoute.js**

```
.when('/board/view/:id/:pg',{
   templateUrl: 'templates/boardview.html',
   controller: 'BoardController'
});
```

**this is my partial BoardController**
//view board

```
var view = function(pg){
   Boards.view(CurrentBoardIdentifier, pg).success(function(response){
      console.log("Request View Completed");
      $scope.board = response;
      console.log(response);
   });
}
```

I didn't understand, why my html file can't access `$scope`.

I set the controller in html and in **appRoute.js** as well.

response in `BoardController` is single json file from express server.

please help me!

Comment: if possible provide your json code.

Comment: I don't have peticular json code but this is schema for board json file. var boardSchema = new Schema({
 seq: {type:Number, default:0},
 title: String,
 writer: String,
 date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 id: String
}, { 
 collection: 'board',
 versionKey: false
});

Comment: your code is perfect, may be its wrong with your json only.